# How to make Android's RelativeLayout work correctly?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

The title is a little provocative, but I observe some behaviour thats inexplicable for me.

I have three sets of views, each having one TextView tvX and one Spinner spX, X=A,B,C. The textview is a title, or prompt, for the spinner, so I want the Spinner layout_toRightOf it's respective TextView. Since they refer to each other, I also layout_alignBaseline the Spinner to the TextView. This works properly. Now I want the three sets stacked such that the TextViews have aligned right edges (each has a trailing colon, these should be aligned), and the Spinners have aligned left edges. So in the stack of

```
  +----------+----------+
  |      tvA:|spA       |
  +----------+----------+
  |      tvB:|spB       |
  +----------+----------+
  |      tvC:|spC       |
  +----------+----------+
```

the B and C views get attributes referring to A and B, respectively; namely layout_below and layout_alignLeft/Right.

It now happens that tvB and tvC have texts that are longer than tvA's. I would have guessed the RelativeLayout indents tvA such that there is space for the longer texts of tvB and tvC, and such that they are right-aligned. What happens instead is that the whole left column gets the width of tvA's text, and tvB and tvC get broken into two lines each. I tentatively tried to rearrange things to make tvB the anchor, and layout_above tvA. This results in tvA completely disappearing. It would not be a proper solution anyway, as in another language the relative lengths of the texts might be the other way! If I add characters to tvA to make it longest, tvB and tvC do not get broken anymore, but the colons still do not get aligned! In fact it looks as if tvB gets centered beneath tvA, and tvC centered beneath tvC.

It sort of looks best if I left-align the tvX and right-align the spX. But even in that situation something strange happens: The Spinners do no obey the attribute layout_width="wrap_content" anymore, they expand instead to fill all the space left over by the TextViews. The ragged alignment in the middle still looks bad, that's why I want the alignment to happen in the middle.

Android Studio displays the resulting layout while editing the XML, and it also displays the Views edges if the cursor is in the XML definition of the View. There I can nicely observe how the layout hints in the attributes get ignored! On the actual phone the same thing happens.

Here is the XML code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/indented_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/settings_sb_device" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/device"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/device_title"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/device_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/can_speed_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/device_title"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/device_title"
            android:text="@string/settings_sb_speed" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/can_speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/can_speed_title"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/can_speed_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/device"
            android:entries="@array/can_speeds" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baudrate_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/can_speed_title"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/can_speed_title"
            android:text="@string/settings_sb_baudrate" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/baudrate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/baudrate_title"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/baudrate_title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/can_speed"
            android:entries="@array/baudrates" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have searched the sets of available attributes for the involved views, but could not find a clue. Can anybody explain this behaviour? What have I overlooked?

Comment: You should use GridLayout for this like what @Ofek Ron said.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `GridLayout` for this with columnCount as 2

For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
                app:columnCount="2"
                app:orientation="vertical"
                >
```

For the left side Tv + colon, use a `RelativeLayout` or even a `LinearLayout` will work for that matter.

```
              <LinearLayout
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_column="0"
                    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
                    app:layout_row="0">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        tools:text="Label"
                        android:maxLines="2"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                   <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        tools:text=":"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
           </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The colon does not have it's own TextView, it's part of the text in the other TextView. I guess I worded this a little ambiguously, sorry for that. When I try GridLayout, the Spinner's text is shown considerably higher than the TextView's, I do bot know how to fix that as I believe there is no layout_alignBaseline tag (if I try it it doesn't do anything).

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that a [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) would fit your needs way better...

Comment: GridLayout has a destinct drawback, which I think is one of the reasons why RelativeLayout should be the better choice here: It does not establish relationships based on contents of views, but only the surrounding rectangles. Hence baseline aligning two views of different type, both with text, is impossible. I cannot baseline align the TextView's text with the Spinner's text. I can vertically center each in the respective grid cell, but since within the Spinner the text is not vertically centered, the baselines do not agree. In RelativeLayout this is fixed by using "layout_alignBaseline".

Comment: I have tried TableLayout now, which I had not used before. Found out it has the same problem as GridLayout in that it seems not to provide any facility to baseline align the row elements. In fact it looks to me as if GridLayout and TableLayout are pretty much the same thing conceptually.

Comment: did you try setting gravity of the spinner to center vertical?